# how does asp.net url routing\directing works?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I was handed over an CLASSIC asp.net site.

I have troubles figuring out the url direction methods.
For exmaple:
      http://localhost/siteName/Story/1/some+title

no .aspx or other extension.

I know MVC routing and I worked a bit with webforms but can't remember there was routing.
I appreciate any kind of assistance. Even what to look for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is tagged as WebForms, is this a classic asp.net site? Is there an App_Start folder?

Comment: What do you need exactly and which version of asp.net web forms are you using? **(1)** Do you need A description about ASP.NET MVC Routing? **(2)** Do you want to know how to handle a request without having an `aspx` form in `WebForms`? **(3)** Do you need to know how to map a friendly url to an `aspx` form?

Comment: it is classic asp.net.  I'm trying to figure out where url routing\translation may occur. how does a url which doesn't map to a physical location it routed.

Comment: did you check Global.asxc.cs file? In Application start you should have RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);...

Comment: there is only global.asax at root level. It has only error handling in it.

Comment: ok. this was a tough one. there was an isapi filter rewrting urls which wasn't installed on my machine when the site was handed over to me. importing the filter and changing the settings to comply with my machine solves the problem. thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC attempts to abstract the file type and file locations away from the user.

In many cases, ASP.NET MVC applications do not modify the routing defaults.

In this case, you typically see this:

The Route = `SiteName/Controller/Route/OptionalParameters`

In your case, you can find the files like so:

In the siteName Project, look for the view (html,css,js) in the `Views/Story` folder.

Look for the server code in the `Controller/StoryController.cs file.`

The routing definition can be in one of two places:

Pre-MVC4: `global.asax`

MVC 4 and above: `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`

Comment: website is old asp.net with webforms not MVC.